# Multittasking Shows Black screen for apps "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend is set to TRUE"

Tags: multitasking, ios7

I am building an app which exits on going to the background.  I have set "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend"  flag  to TRUE.

#### Multitasking feature

> Keep the content of your app up-to-date by adopting the new
>   multitasking APIs in iOS 7. The new services allow your app to update
>   information and download content in the background without draining
>   the battery unnecessarily. The updates can happen at opportunistic
>   times and are intelligently scheduled according to usage, so your app
>   can update content in the background just when your users need it." to
>   do this "Double Press the Home Button

My app screen is shown as black screen in multitasking tray/app switcher till it comes into foreground.

Is there a way to show launch graphics/splash screen when the app is in the background during Multitasking tray/ app-switcher?

Can anyone please let me know how to show the launch graphics of my app during multitasking.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution? If not, did you find any reliable documentation that states that it is an expected behavior?

Comment: Anyone? This problem is the last to-do on my app!

Comment: Forget that last comment. I didn't understand what you wanted precisely. However, because you've set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `TRUE`, the process is exited *not* terminated when you close it. You could subclass your App Delegate's mainWindow, add a UIImageView and set the content of that when you `applicationDidEnterBackground:`